# jquery sortable() complete callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table with two columns - row number and name

The table has to be sortable by user (using drag and drop).

Here is html of table:

```
<table class="table table-striped sorted_table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody-list">
            <tr>
                <td class='td-index'>1</td>
                <td>Frank</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='td-index'>2</td>
                <td>Bill</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='td-index'>3</td>
                <td>John</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='td-index'>4</td>
                <td>David</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='td-index'>5</td>
                <td>Elisa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='td-index'>6</td>
                <td>Anna</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Here is jquery for sorting (drag and drop):

```
$('.sorted_table').sortable({
    containerSelector: 'table',
    itemPath: '> tbody',
    itemSelector: 'tr',
    placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>',
    update: function( event, ui) {
        $('.td-index').each(function(index ) {
            index++;
            $(this).text(index );
        })
    }
})
```

I used `update` callback function of `sorting()` to regenerate the number of the each row after every sorting - but it doesn't

What callback function should I use?

Comment: can you please post a JSFiddle ? so it will be very easy

Comment: see the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/45j4vm92/

Comment: awesome answer  Frebin , you can add it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

try `beforeStop` or `stop` instead of update